# Duplicates in JSP's include directive

Tags: jsp, methods, include, multiple-instances

This code is not real, but is simpler and show the problem

Suppose that I have First File named 
**Base.jsp**

```
<%!
  class Base {
    public String Parm0 = "";
    public String Parm1 = "";

    Base () {
      PrintMessage("Base Created!!");
    }
  }
  javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter Out;
  void SetJspWriter(javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out) {
    Out = out;
  }

  void PrintMessage(String Msg) {
    try {
      Out.print("<P style=\"color:rgb(255,0,0)\">"+Msg+"</P>");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
  }
%>
```

Now I have a Second File that use the base file:
**Fil0.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="Base.jsp" %>
<%!
  class File0 {
    public Base MyBase;
    File0 () {
      MyBase = new Base();
      PrintMessage("Based Used!!");
    }
  }
%>
```

Now I have a Third File that use the base file:
**Fil1.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="Base.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="Fil0.jsp" %>
<%!
  class File1 {
    public Base MyBase;
    public File0 MyFil0;
    File1 () {
      MyBase = new Base();
      MyFil0 = new File0();
      PrintMessage("Based and Fil0 Created!!");
    }
  }
%>
<%
  SetJspWriter(out);
  File1 MyFil1 = new File1();
%>
```

As you can see... this code will produce messages like:

**Duplicate field Fil1_jsp.Out**

**Duplicate method PrintMessage(String) in type Fil1_jsp**

How solve this error
Before I need to include Base in two files: File0 and File1.
And File1 have Base and File0...

The compiler find two declarations...

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the line: `javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter Out;` only in the last file `Fil1.jsp`, I think that with the includes you're actually declaring the same object more than once.

Also, you have `File0()` constructor inside class `File1`.

Further, since you included Base.jsp in File0.jsp, and then included both Base.jsp and File0.jsp in File1.jsp - you're actually included Base.jsp twice!

If you want to see exactly what's going on, look for the compiled jsp: your jsp files are compiled to `.java` and can usually be found under tomcat `/work` folder, in linux it's something like: `/usr/local/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp`

Comment: That's great, cause that's not my real answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for how to manage the includes directives, maybe there is other alternative, or indicate the multiplicity of same code....

Comment: @Anita I included a comment in regards in my answer above.